# On Demand Image Cacheing with Service Workers

Tags: javascript, image, caching

For the past few days I’ve been struggling with replacing an App Cache based application with service workers. The challenge is we only want the script to check for a new image when a new image exists, similar to how you could update the app cache manifest to indicate a new image is available.

Everything I find talks about online vs offline strategies. I'm looking for an on demand approach where the page only checks and caches new content when the server has new content available. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `when the server has new content available.`  What can we use to know this?

Comment: in the old app cache model the server could edit the manifest file, then js on the page checked the updated date on the manifest file and if it was more recent then the last time it retrieved content it would download and cache content. I'd like to use a similar model where the server updates a file or trigger that tells the page new content is available.

Comment: If your happy how App Cache works, you might find this useful. -> https://github.com/kenchris/jakecache